# Easiest way to create a road line effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

hello I want to create a road line in illustrator like in this picture. The line must be the same or like this.

[image: road]

I want to make it with holes and give the line an effect like an asphalt line.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you want to achieve and what you have tried; therefore it is very difficult for us to help you. You need to provide as much information and screenshots as possible.

Comment: Cleared comments because they gave no new information. We need questions to show as much effort as it's expected of answers, we are here to help each other learn and improve but that requires a commitment by both sides. That is why your question was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do something like this in Illustrator is to use **Brushes** to apply a distressed stroke.

Simply open the Artistic Charcoal and Chalk brushes:

[image]

Then simply draw a path and click one of the brushes in the panel that opens:
[image]

---

The other option would be to use a texture file and create a clipping path or use Pathfinder to subtract a texture from a shape.